# Big-O Notation of multiple statements

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Suppose there are multiple functions with certain big o notations, anything O(N), O(N^2), etc.
If you have a code fragment such as.

```
 f1(x);
 f2(x);
 f3(x);
```

Are all the big O notations added together or multiplied? Any explanation as to why either would be correct - addition or multiplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.  You would take the maximum.

Calling the larger piece of code `g`...  If for example O(`f2`) >= O(`f1`) and O(`f2`) >= O(`f3`), then the complexity of `g` is <= 3 * O(`f2`) = O(`f2`).

Comment: In fact, they are added, but `O(n^3 + n^2 + n)`, for example, is equivalent to `O(n^3)`.  If rare circumstances it's important to understand the lower-order terms in the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they don't modify `x`, then the O notations are added together, since the time taken to do all three is the sum of the time taken to do each individually.